# Error Class 'Database\Seeders\Opportunity' not found

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-artisan

**I found this error when i run a command of php artisan db:seed
please help me to solve this error**

**My code is**

**opportunitySeeder.php**

```
<?php

namespace Database\Seeders;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB;
use Illuminate\Database\Seeder;

class OpportunitySeeder extends Seeder
{
    /**
     * Run the database seeds.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function run()
    {
        //factory(Opportunity::class, 300)->create()
        //Opportunity::factory()->count(200)->create()
        //factory(Opportunity::class, 300)->create()->each(function($opportunity){
           // $opportunity->$detail()->save(factory(OpportunityDetail::class)->make());

            Opportunity::factory()->count(300)->create()->each(function($opportunity) {
                $opportunity->detail()->save(OpportunityDeail::factory()->make()
                );

        });
    }
}
```

**OpportunitFactory**

> $this->faker->sentence(150, true),
>             'description' =>$this->faker->text(500),
>             'category_id' =>Category::all()->random()->id,
>             'country_id' =>Country::all()->random()->id,
>             'deadline' =>$this->faker->dateTime(),
>             'organizer' =>$this->faker->company,
>             
>         ];
>     } }

Comment: Well, does the class `Database\Seeders\Opportunity` exist with that exact namespace? If it has a different namespace, you need to `use` it first.

Comment: You have to import use statement for Opportunity model: `use App\Models\Opportunity` as well as for OpportunityDetail `use App\Models\OpportunityDetail;` and you also have a typo `save(OpportunityDeail::factory()` it should be `save(OpportunityDetail::factory()`

Comment: Hi did you tried **php artisan db:seed --class OpportunitySeeder**

Answer (score 0):

This is probably because you're not pulling in Opportunity model. Something like this should fix the issue.

```
<?php

namespace Database\Seeders;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB;
use Illuminate\Database\Seeder;
use App\Models\Opportunity;

class OpportunitySeeder extends Seeder
{
    /**
     * Run the database seeds.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function run()
    {

            Opportunity::factory()->count(300)->create()->each(function($opportunity) {
                $opportunity->detail()->save(OpportunityDeail::factory()->make()
                );

        });
    }
}
```

Note : I just added "use App\Models\Opportunity;" at the top

Answer (score 0):

There was major changes in migration and seeder so you have to do the following

rename your seeds folder to seeders and add the namespace in each and every seeder file

namespace Database\Seeders;

Also make changes in composer file
remove classmap from autoload and add this in psr-4

```
"autoload": {
    "psr-4": {
        "App\\": "app/",
        "Database\\Factories\\": "database/factories/",
        "Database\\Seeders\\": "database/seeders/"
    }
},
```